# Finding $\lim_{n \to \infty}\left(\frac{2^{\frac{1}{n}}}{n+1}+\frac{2^{\frac{2}{n}}}{n+\frac{1}{2}}+\cdots+\frac{2^{\frac{n}{n}}}{n+\frac1n}\right)$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits, definite-integrals, geometric-series

I am trying to determine

$$\lim_{n \to \infty}\left(\frac{2^{\frac{1}{n}}}{n+1}+\frac{2^{\frac{2}{n}}}{n+\frac{1}{2}}+\cdots+\frac{2^{\frac{n}{n}}}{n+\frac1n}\right)$$

Heres is my attempt:
I know that if $\lim a_n=:a$, and $\lim b_n = :b$
we get that $\lim (a_n+b_n)=a+b$

Obviously

$$\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \frac{2^{\frac{1}{2}}}{n+1}=0$$

$$\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \frac{2^{\frac{2}{n}}}{n+\frac{1}{2}}=0$$

The only thing left is to determine

$$\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \frac{2^{\frac{n}{n}}}{n+\frac{1}{n}}=0$$

Thus we get that
$$\lim_{n \to \infty}\left(\frac{2^{\frac{1}{n}}}{n+1}+\frac{2^{\frac{2}{n}}}{n+\frac{1}{2}}+\cdots+\frac{2^{\frac{n}{n}}}{n+\frac1n}\right) = 0$$

My question is if my approach is correct. Especially because this exercise was labled "very difficult", which it really does not seem like.

Comment: How many terms do you think there are in that limit?

Comment: If $\lim a_n=:a$, and $\lim b_n = :b$
we get that $\lim (a_n+b_n)=a+b$: this helps only when the number of terms is two or some other  fixed number.

Comment: @geetha290krm this works not only for two terms, but for every finite number of terms

Comment: @Zima The pedagogical problem is that the number of terms, $n$, is finite for each $n$.  The fact that we'd need infinitely many terms to encode a triangular array isn't clear to everyone.

Comment: Yeah my mistake was to think that the $k$ index was fixed. But since it dapends on $n$... .Thanks for the notice

Answer (score 4, accepted):

\begin{align}
\lim_{n\to\infty}\sum_{j=1}^n\frac{2^{\frac jn}}{n+\frac 1j} &=\lim_{n\to \infty}\frac1n \sum_{j=1}^n\frac{2^{\frac jn}}{1+\frac 1{jn}}\\
&=\int_0^12^xdx
\end{align}

Comment: ups, you are right :-) thanks, just fixed.

Comment: Does this really converge to that integral? It's not that obvious (at least to me) since the sum is not just expressed in terms of $\frac{j}{n}$, so it's not the Riemann sum of a function?

Comment: @BrunoB I would agree it requires an argument, but it's not hard.  The absolute difference between $2^{j/n}$ and $\frac{2^{j/n}}{1+\frac1{jn}}$ is at most $2\cdot \frac{1}{jn+1} \leq 2/n$ so it sums to at most $2$, which when divided by $n$ goes to $0$ in the limit.

Comment: @BrianMoehring Thanks for the explanation!

Comment: sorry for not adding details and thanks to Brian Moehring :-)

Answer (score 2):

We have that

$$\sum_{j=1}^n\frac{2^{\frac jn}}{n+\frac 1j}=\frac1n\sum_{j=1}^n\frac{2^{\frac jn}}{1+\frac 1{jn}}\to \frac1{\log 2}$$

indeed

$$\frac{2^{\frac jn}}{1+\frac 1{n}}\le \frac{2^{\frac jn}}{1+\frac 1{jn}}\le \frac{2^{\frac jn}}{1+\frac 1{n^2}}$$

$$\frac1{n+1}\sum_{j=1}^n2^{\frac jn}\le \frac1n\sum_{j=1}^n\frac{2^{\frac jn}}{1+\frac 1{jn}}\le \frac 1{n+\frac1n}\sum_{j=1}^n2^{\frac jn}$$

and by geometric series $\sum_{j=1}^n2^{\frac jn}=\frac{2^\frac1n}{2^\frac1n-1}$, thus

$$\frac {n2^\frac1n}{n+1}\frac{\frac1n}{2^\frac1n-1}\le \frac1n\sum_{j=1}^n\frac{2^{\frac jn}}{1+\frac 1{jn}}\le \frac {n2^\frac1n}{n+\frac1n}\frac{\frac1n}{2^\frac1n-1}$$

with $$\frac{\frac 1n}{2^\frac1n-1} \to \frac1{\log 2}$$